# Passing data between components does not work Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem, I am trying to pass the `playlist[]` array from component.ts to header.ts.

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Code below:

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faRedo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faHeadphones } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faExternalLinkAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent {

  public data = [];
  public playlist = [];
  public apiData: any;
  public results = [];
  public loading = false;
  public noData: any;
  p: number = 1;
  faSearch = faSearch;
  faRedo = faRedo;
  faHeadphones = faHeadphones;
  faExternalLinkAlt = faExternalLinkAlt;
  faPlus = faPlus;

  searchQuery: string = "";
  clickMessage = '';

  constructor(private service: ApiService) { }


  getAll() {
    this.service.getAll(this.searchQuery).subscribe((results) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
      this.loading = false;

      if (this.data.length <= 0) {
        this.noData = true;
      } else if (this.data.length >= 1) {
        this.noData = false;
      } else {
        this.noData = false;
      }
    })
  }

  closeAlert() {
    this.noData = false;
  }

  addSongToPlaylist(itunes) {
    this.playlist.push(itunes);
    console.log('Playlist - ', this.playlist);
}

  refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  Search() {
    this.service.getAll(this.searchQuery).subscribe((results) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Artwork</th>
              <th>Artist</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Genre</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let user of playlist">
              <td><img src="{{user.artworkUrl60}}"></td>
              <td>{{user.artistName}}</td>
              <td>{{user.collectionName}}</td>
              <td>{{user.primaryGenreName}}</td>
              <td>{{user.collectionPrice}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

page.html

```
<app-header [playlist]="playlist"></app-header>
    <app-content></app-content>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**header.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { faHeadphones} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  faHeadphones = faHeadphones;

  @Input()playlist = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**header.html**

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{playlist.length}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: `playlist` is in your `component.ts` so you can bind it in `component.html`, but you use it in `page.html`?

Comment: By default, one template file, `.html` is linked to one component file `.ts`. E.g. `content-component.html` is linked to `content-component.ts`. The properties you have defined in `content-component.ts` is only accessible by it's linked `content-component.html`. E.g. `playlist` property. The additional page.html does not have access to the properties defined in `content-component.ts`. `page.html` can only access, I assume, a `page.ts` properties. Unless you also define a "playlist" property in `page.ts`.

Comment: no playlist is not defined in page.ts

Comment: That's why you are getting `playlist is undefined` error ... A little tip for you... do take a pencil and paper and draft/draw out how you want your components to interact with each other before setting out to code...  can save you a lot of headache in the long run ...

Comment: Also, if you are trying to use the playlist property in `content-component.ts`, then you will need to use `@Output()`. Do read the article I had shared with you in the other question.

Comment: Thanks, the error has gone but there is no length on the list now either

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the object inside `playlist` is the same as the beginning. Try to clone the object and add the new item to the clone item:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faRedo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faHeadphones } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faExternalLinkAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent {

  public data = [];
  public playlist = [];
  public apiData: any;
  public results = [];
  public loading = false;
  public noData: any;
  p: number = 1;
  faSearch = faSearch;
  faRedo = faRedo;
  faHeadphones = faHeadphones;
  faExternalLinkAlt = faExternalLinkAlt;
  faPlus = faPlus;

  searchQuery: string = "";
  clickMessage = '';

  constructor(private service: ApiService) { }

 ...
  addSongToPlaylist(itunes) {
    const playlistSong = {...this.playlist};
    playlistSong.push(itunes);
    this.playlist = playlistSong;
    console.log('Playlist - ', this.playlist);
  }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to output playlist from component then assign that into a variable in your page component then can pass it to app header:

```
<app-header [playlist]="playlist"></app-header>
<app-content [playlistOutputEvent]="playlist = $event;"></app-content>
```

Comment: That breaks it completely with error: `Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 12 in [playlist = $event;] in`

Comment: add this [playlistOutputEvent]="playlist = $event;" not [playlist = $event;]